# Read data from dynamically generated forms with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, python-requests

so ive an HTML page that have multiple generated forms:

```
{% for row in data %}
    <form action="/aggiorna_pratica" method='POST' id="inserisci_app_{{ row[0][1] }}">
       <input name="id_pratica_{{ row[0][1] }}" type='hidden 'id="id_pratica_{{ row[0][1] }}" value="{{ row[0][1] }}"></input> 

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aggiorna_app">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
       </button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

row[0][1] contains the id of the row.

Im trying to send ajax requests from every single one of them, but i get the same ID of the frist row from every row.

This is the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { $(".aggiorna_app").click(function(event) { 
//prevent submit
event.preventDefault(); //Thx @alex

//do things on submit
$.ajax({
    data : {
        tipo_richiesta : "inserisci_intervento",
        id : $('#id_pratica').val(),
        data_int : $('#data_int').val(),
        ora_int : $('#ora_int').val()
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/aggiorna_pratica",
    beforeSend: function(){
        //Before send data
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

});
});

I know im a newbie but i could really use some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example to test your click event. The click event is on `.aggoriorna_app` buttons inside each form, but the id being passed into the ajax call looks to be grabbing the `.val()` every time, e.g, `$('#id_pratica').val()`. You'll see in my example that when a button is clicked, find the nearest input value and set the ajax id to that value. I assume that's what you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".aggiorna_app").click(function(event) { 
            //prevent submit
            event.preventDefault(); //Thx @alex
    
            var id = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
            alert(id);
        });
    });
```

```css
form {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <form action="/aggiorna_pratica" method='POST' id="inserisci_app_{{ row[0][1] }}">
        <input name="id_pratica_{{ row[0][1] }}" type='hidden 'id="id_pratica_1" value="input_1"></input> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aggiorna_app">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>CLICK ME
        </button>
    </form>
    <form action="/aggiorna_pratica" method='POST' id="inserisci_app_{{ row[0][1] }}">
        <input name="id_pratica_{{ row[0][1] }}" type='hidden 'id="id_pratica_2" value="input_2"></input> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aggiorna_app">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>CLICK ME
        </button>
    </form>
    <form action="/aggiorna_pratica" method='POST' id="inserisci_app_{{ row[0][1] }}">
        <input name="id_pratica_{{ row[0][1] }}" type='hidden 'id="id_pratica_3" value="input_3"></input> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aggiorna_app">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>CLICK ME
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The id is just a unique number for every form, but everytime the fuction only return the one at the start of the list(just the id of the frist form even i click the submit button of the other forms), .aggiorna_app is just a function that send the forms data(all the other parameters are in the form, i just didint paste it here, but i case you need it i will).

Comment: And yes that just a typo, in the code there not such error.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm assuming that the ajax id needs to be unique each time but your id looks like it's set to the same value no matter which button is clicked.